# Error in wxwidgets in windows

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

When i create a  simple application with  wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wxBORDER_NONE as below

```
#include <wx/wx.h>class Simple : public wxFrame

class Simple : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Simple(const wxString& title);

};


Simple::Simple(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(250,     150),wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR | wxBORDER_NONE)
{
  Centre();
}


class MyApp : public wxApp
{
  public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};


IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    Simple *simple = new Simple(wxT("Simple"));
simple->Show(true);

return true;
}
```

When i try to shut down the computer while this application is running, it shows "The instruction at 0x00780065 referenced memory at 0x00780065 The memory could not be written".

To prevent logging off, you can do the following
Start a notepad, and type something. Then start the compiled program. Then try to log off. You will see the error. When the notepad asks if you want to save, do nothing. After some seconds, a window will pop up with option to force log off. Click cancel. In this way you can repeat the problem without logging off.

Comment: _What_ error...? "It shows an error" does not allow us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle the close event.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_close_event.html

Note especially the discussion of EVT_END_SESSION